# Php Static Class is Constantly Reinitialized on Every Use

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to Php, so this might be a dumb question. I'm currently trying to build in logging functionality for my app, and I'd like the logger I'm using to just be instantiated once to make the whole thing faster (i.e. instead of instantiating a new logger for every logcall I make). I've read about how Singletons in Php are bad and since static stuff is easier to use and gets better benchmarks, I'm fine with basically making the class static. Here's my current code:

```
use Fluent\Logger\FluentLogger;

class Logger
{
    private static $_fluentLogger;
    private static $_initialized;

    public static function getLogger()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$_initialized)) 
        {
            Fluent\Autoloader::register();
            self::$_fluentLogger = new FluentLogger("localhost","34567");
            self::$_initialized = true;
            self::$_fluentLogger->post("debug.test",array("initializing"=>"true"));
        }
        return self::$_fluentLogger;
    }
}
```

Then to call the thing, I do:

```
$logger = Logger::getLogger();
self::$_fluentLogger->post("debug.test",array("real_post"=>"true"));
```

My problem is that every time I call the thing to post by doing the above, I can see it also writing out the "initializing"=>"true" message (i.e. reinitializing the logger each time). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're doing nothing wrong, PHP is stateless, so the static class is initialized once per every request (not per session)

Comment: OK, so what can I do to just initialize something once per session?

Comment: set session variable? save values valid for session in session variables. and just reinit from these on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not persist states between sessions. If you want to have the functionality, use a **[SESSION variable](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)**.